# JPA eclipseLink: lazy properties included in join query

Tags: jpa, join, eclipselink, lazy-evaluation

EclipseLink 2.6.3, clob lazy properties are included in join query, leading to

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB
```

for oracle database.

For example,  a Sales order has a number of OrderItem(s), and OrderItem entity refers to Product entity which as a lazy CLOB property: description.

1. Search Products: the clob property is not included in query selection. GOOD.
2. Search OrderItem join Product, the lazy product.description will be included in query selection. ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB. Is this a bug?

Example: OrderItem refers to Product. Group by products to get sales total for each products ordering by sales total descending.

```
  select product,sum(total) from OrderItem group by product order by sum(total) desc

    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Object[]> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Object[].class);
    Root<OrderItem> root = criteriaQuery.from(OrderItem.class);
    Path<Product> product = root.get("product");
    Expression<BigDecimal> total = criteriaBuilder.sum(root.get("total"));
    criteriaQuery.multiselect(product, total);
    criteriaQuery.groupBy(product);

    TypedQuery<Object[]> query = em.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
    List<Object[]> students = query.getResultList();
```

SQL:

```
     SELECT * FROM (SELECT a.*, ROWNUM rnum  FROM (SELECT t0.ID AS a1, 
t0.DESCRIPTION AS a2, t0.MODEL AS a3, t0.NAME AS a4, t0.VERSION AS a5, 
SUM(t1.QUANTITY), SUM(t1.TOTAL) FROM Product t0, OrderItem t1 WHERE (t0.ID = 
t1.productId) GROUP BY t0.ID, t0.DESCRIPTION, t0.MODEL, t0.NAME, t0.VERSION ORDER
BY SUM(t1.TOTAL) DESC) a WHERE ROWNUM <= 20) WHERE rnum > 0;
```

Product.description is declared to be lazy using @Basic(fetch=FetchType.LAZY). But it is included in SQL, causing the CLOB issue for oracle db.  If I removed the t0.description in select and groupBy, it will work in SQLPLUS. But EclipseLink ignored the lazy and fetch all properties of Product.

Note that the groupBy in the generated by SQL includes all fields of Product. It looks very inefficient if the product has 50 fields.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't completely follow the problem, but how can an inconsistent datatype error depend on whether a join is done eagerly or lazily?

Comment: Oracle database does not like CLOB comparison such as in select DISTINCT product.description, ....

Comment: the JPQL is? and the generated SQL is?

Comment: Added generated SQL. thanks.

Comment: Is this the actual JPQL being used?  Since you are ordering on Product, it cannot work, since the clob is then required in the grouping.  Try instead to select and group on the product.id rather then the whole product object.

Comment: No. It is not real JPQL. I used CriteriaQuery. I can group by product.id instead of product object, but need to return product object in selection. The lazy clob property will still be in the selection list, causing the same problem. Thanks.

Comment: added CriteriaQuery code.